# Combine And/Or with PredicateBuilder?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, predicatebuilder

I have a list of `Ids` and I only want to do an `AND` on the first one and and `OR` on the subsequent ones.  In the past, I have kept a `counter` variable and when the `counter` is 1, I do the `And`, but after that I do an `OR`, but I was curious if there was an easier way:

```
foreach(string id in Ids)
{
   predicate.And(x=> id.Contains(x.id)); //I want to do an And only on the first id.
}
```

This is what I have done in the past, but is there a more concise way:

```
int counter = 1;
foreach (var Id in Ids)
{
     string i = Id;
     if (counter == 1)
     {
         predicate = predicate.And(x => i.Contains(x.id));
         counter++;
      }
      else
      {
           predicate = predicate.Or(x=>i.Contains(x.id));
          counter++;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with a local copy of PredicateBuilder (no entityFramework or LinkToSql available at work):

```
var firstID = ids.First();
predicate.And(x => firstID.Contains(x.id));

foreach (string id in ids.Skip(1))
{
    var localID = id;   //access to a modified closure otherwise
    predicate.Or(x => localID.Contains(x.id)); 
}
```

Comment: The one with And gives me the errror: `{"Unable to create a constant value of type 'Closure type'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."}`. ids is a string[]

Comment: @xaisoft: which line gives that error? the `And` or the `Or`?

Comment: @Pondidum Probably the first.  Just call `ids.First()` outside of the lambda so that it isn't compiled into the expression.

Comment: @Servy: yeah, I am just writing a testapp to check it first

Comment: This works, but it works just like  my original way with just using a string.Contains.

Comment: @Pondidum - Ok, I just changed the contains to == because since I am now iterating over each id, contains brought back incorrect results where == did not. Thanks!