# How to order a list of entities by a custom order?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a list of entities that could be represented like that:

```
Type | Property A | Property B | ... 
--------------------------------------
A    | ABC        | 123        | ...
A    | ABC        | 123        | ...
D    | ABC        | 123        | ...
D    | ABC        | 123        | ...
B    | ABC        | 123        | ...
C    | ABC        | 123        | ...
```

**Type** is a string and can only be one of 4 distinct values (e. g A, B, C, D)
I need to order these entities by **Type** but with a custom order (e. g. A, D, B, C).

I tried something like this:

```
var orderType = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
                    { "A", 0 },
                    { "D", 1 },
                    { "B", 2 },
                    { "C", 3 }
                };
return db.MyEntity
         .OrderBy(x => orderType[x.Type])
         .ToList();
```

But I get the following error:

*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

I don't understand this error and don't know what to do with this OrderBy. Could you please tell me how to order these entities by **Type** with a custom order?

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is because EntityFramework will need to send teh Dictionary over to SQL in some way, which it cannot do efficiently.

Comment: You can achieve this by telling EntityFramework how to translate your dictionary to a function based on predicates. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16839341/736079

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand this error

It's because LINQ TO SQL cannot translate `Int32 get_Item(System.String)` of Dictionary into an equivalent operation in SQL.

---

A very simple way to solve it  is to bring entities in memory by `AsEnumerable()` :

```
return db.MyEntity.AsEnumerable().
         .OrderBy(x => orderType[x.Type])
         .ToList();
```

Comment: Is there any solution to not bring it in memory?